# Has China always decided to not criticize Hamas or was there some kind of policy shift?

Tags: china, israel, palestine, hamas

> China has long backed the Palestinians and been quick to denounce
> Israel over its settlements in the occupied territories. It has not
> criticized the initial Hamas attack on Oct.7 — which killed about
> 1,200 people — while the United States and others have called it an
> act of terrorism. However, China does have growing economic ties with
> Israel.

https://www.pbs.org/newshour/world/china-hosts-arab-and-muslim-foreign-ministers-to-discuss-ending-the-israel-hamas-war

Has China always decided to not criticize Hamas or was there some kind of policy shift? I am guessing it never criticized Hamas given its ties with the Global South and that the Oct 7 attack was the biggest attack carried out against Israel, but I was wondering if I could be wrong.

Comment: They voted the same way in 2018 at the UN. IDK if they gave some kind of verbal condemnation elsewhere, but I rather doubt they did. The grammar in the title of the Q could use some simplification though.

Comment: I was writing an answer, but I think that this [al-Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/6/china-takes-cautious-approach-to-diplomacy-over-israel-gaza-war) article more or less summarizes what I would have written. Basically, lingering sympathies with Palestine due to historical ties to the PLO, but recognition of stronger present economic ties with Israel. Initial statements were typically ambivalent, reflecting China's goal of positioning itself as a neutral mediator and its lack of genuine investment in the conflict, whether in favor of Hamas or the Israeli government.

Comment: But while the initial statements basically blamed no one or everyone and called for peace and a two-state solution in vague terms, some diplomats started taking a more explicitly pro-Palestinian tone with even a bit of criticism of Israel thrown in, albeit mainly restricted to specific actions—not a lot of "liberate Palestine from the river to the sea" coming from Chinese officials—as they saw that Arab trading partners would more or less demand it.